# Azure Enterprise Service Bus: Using GetQueues with multiple filters

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

Currently I'm pulling down the queues from the service bus to create statistics for monitoring.
I only want to pull certain queues down so I am using the GetQueues filter and looking for a prefix. eg.

```
var queueDescriptions = await NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(csi.Value).GetQueuesAsync($"startswith(path, 'Skywalker') eq true")
```

There are two prefixes I would like to look for though. There isn't much documentation on the filters, is it possible to write a single filter than can look for either prefix or do I need to pull twice from the service bus and concatenate the results?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.getqueuesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_GetQueuesAsync_System_String_) you can use multliple filters in your calls.
The only allowed logical operator is `AND`. So something like

`startswith(path, 'queue') eq true AND messageCount gt 0`

would work.